# Python check condition in all on empty list

Tags: python

is it normal behavior ?

```
answer=all(c=='false True answer?' for c in [])
# answer = True
```

will it be ok if i want False on check values by "all" at empty list to use such line ?:

```
answer=all(set([c=='a' for c in []]) or [False,])
```

looks ok if:

```
answer=all(set([c=='a' for c in ['a','a']]) or [False,])
answer=all(set([c=='a' for c in ['a','b']]) or [False,])
```

i decide to use reverse logic such as:

```
bad_answer=bool([c for c in ['a','b'] if c!='a'])
```

Comment: There is no False, so all is True…

Comment: but c is not equal to string ? or it's not even compared?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`all()` is documented](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all) as

> Return True if all elements of the iterable are true (or if the
>   iterable is empty).

Your generator expression `c=='false True answer?' for c in []` is empty because it iterates over an empty list. The comparison never happens because there is nothing `in []`.

Answer (score 3):

```
In [2]: all([])
Out[2]: True
```

Yes.

`c == '...'` never gets evaluated because the `for c in []` admits no items. The list comprehension evaluates to `[]` immediately when the `iterable` in `for c in iterable` is empty.

Answer (score 3):

You're checking if all the elements of an empty list are equal to some value. Because there are no values in the list, technically all the values *are* equal to that other value.

```
>>> all([])
True
```

`all` returns `False` if any of the expressions evaluate to `False`, or `True` otherwise. Because none of the conditions are not true (since there are none in the first place), `all` returns `True`.

Answer (score 1):

`all` always evaluates to `True` when operating on an empty sequence. So yes, it's normal.